# Import React statement syntax error creating a problem

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error in an index.js file. I'm trying to make a simple react, javascript project using an api as well.

```
/*
import React from 'react'; // this enables jsx
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
*/
```

**My code looks like this:**

```
/*import React from 'react'; // this enables jsx
import ReactDOM from '...react-dom'; // this allows us to attach the APP
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'; // this allows front end routing

import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Activities from './Activities';
import MyRoutines from './MyRoutines';
import Register from './Register';
import Routines from './Routines';


const PORT = 3000;
const express = require('express');
const { client } = require('./db/client');
const server = express();

function App() {
*/
```

Comment: What is the node version you are using?

Comment: node version is v12.19.0

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

A lot of interfaces still do not understand ES6 Javascript syntax/features, hence there is a need for Es6 to be compiled to ES5 whenever it is used in any file or project. The possible reasons for the SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module error is you are trying to run the file independently, you are yet to install and set up an Es6 compiler such as Babel or the path of the file in your runscript is wrong/not the compiled file. If you will want to continue without a compiler the best possible solution is to use ES5 syntax which in your case would be `var react = require('react');` this can later be updated as appropriate or better still setup your compiler and ensure your file/project is compiled before running and also ensure your run script is running the compiled file usually named dist, build or whatever you named it and the path to the compiled file in your runscript is correct.

### Method 2

Add "type": "module" to your package.json

```
{
  // ...
  "type": "module",
  // ...
}
```

Note: When using modules, if you get ReferenceError: require is not defined, you'll need to use the import syntax instead of require.

### Method 3

Update node.